# Querying a GraphDB server through Jena

Tags: jena, graphdb

I'm trying to query a GraphDB repository on a server from java code where I'm using Jena. According to the GraphDB documentation (http://graphdb.ontotext.com/free/using-graphdb-with-jena.html#installing-graphdb-with-jena), it's possible to instatiate a model using Jena SesameDataset as follow :

```
import com.ontotext.jena.SesameDataset;
// Some code goes here...
SesameDataset dataset = new SesameDataset(repositoryConnection);
Model model = 
ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(dataset.getDefaultGraph());
```

I'm looking for the "Jena SesameDataSet" library from a couple of days without success.

Do you know where I can find it (maven or jar file) ? Or ***do you know any mean of instantiating a jena Model that is backed by a GraphDB repository on a server (whose URL can be something like http://localhost:7200/repositories/TestRepo) ?***

Comment: Use Jena's `RDFConnection` (a remote connection) to send SPARQL query operations to the GraphDB database.

Comment: Thank you @AndyS. But, what if in addition of SPARQL query execution, I also want to access data properties or object properties as follows : ` OntProperty myProperty = myJenaModel.getOntProperty(myPropertyName)` ? This is the reason why I want a Jena Model backed by my GraphDB database.

Comment: You can ask that in SPARQL. If you want API access , its a question for GraphDB - I don't know how SesameDataset worsk - the example is for a quite old version of Jena.

Comment: See https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/using-graphdb-with-jena.html